# Android Tab navigation in different activities

Tags: android

I tried to implement 3 tabs in android using the google tutorial.....but i am unable to create different activities for each one and navigate through them....

```
package com.example.tab;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Important-the following code in onCreate class adds tabs to action 
    // bar

    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // show the given tab

        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // hide the given tab

        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
                FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // probably ignore this event
        }
    };

    // Now we add 3 Tabs specifying tab names and Tablistener
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Tech")
                    .setTabListener(tabListener));

        }
        if (i == 1) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Politics")
                    .setTabListener(tabListener));  

        }
        if (i == 2) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Sports")
                    .setTabListener(tabListener));

        }

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // Method to add action bar
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}


}
```

What should I try after this and creating 3 activities for each tab??

Comment: why are you looping to create the tabs, you dont need to loop just create them. If you dont know how to start an activity you should look here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#StartingAnActivity

Answer (score 0):

You should create just one Activity with a ViewPager and multiple Fragments (one for each tab). [This tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) describes how to do this.

Next you can listen for the selection of an action bar tab to change the viewpager and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FragmentActivity` and `Fragment` for Tab and its different view in Activity.

see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) for `ActionBar` Tab and for [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)